# Removing lines whose first column is duplicated

Tags: awk, sed, grep, string, search

I have a file where strings are separated by a special string (not a comma or delimiter) e.g. `<vvv>`. I want to check if all strings in the first field are unique. If duplicate rows for the same field found, I want to remove any repeated rows (leave the first occurrence).

Example:

```
aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
aaa<vvv>new<vvv>new2
111<vvv>222<vvv>333
```

I want to get:

```
aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
111<vvv>222<vvv>333
```

We removed `aaa<vvv>new<vvv>new2` because `aaa` has appeared already.

I do not prefer to us `awk` unless if it is the only solution. Its syntax is a bit complex to me as an unfamiliar to Linux.

Comment: Is the ordering of the lines in the result important?

Comment: Yes. I prefer to keep everything as is. Just remove duplicates.

Comment: @user9371654L Why tag `awk` if you can't use it? It is as-straightforward as it could get, if used with `awk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using `awk` *very much*:

```
$ awk -v OFS="<" '{ print NR, $0 }' file | sort -t '<' -u -k2,2 | sort -t '<' -k1,1n | cut -d '<' -f 2-
aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
111<vvv>222<vvv>333
```

This only uses `awk` to insert a line number followed by `<` into the original data. We do this to be able to keep track of the ordering of the original lines.  We use `<` as the delimiter between the line number and the rest of the line because this also appears as the delimiter between the original first field and the rest of the line.

After the first stage of the pipeline, in which `awk` is used to insert the line numbers, the data will look like

```
1<aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
2<xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
3<aaa<vvv>new<vvv>new2
4<111<vvv>222<vvv>333
```

The next step of the pipeline sorts this on the second field (the first original field), removing duplicates. The result will be

```
4<111<vvv>222<vvv>333
1<aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
2<xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
```

The second `sort` restores the original line order by sorting the lines on the first field numerically, and we get

```
1<aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
2<xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
4<111<vvv>222<vvv>333
```

The `cut` then removes the numbers from the first field (and the inserted delimiter).

---

A solution that gives ordered output without using `awk` at all would look like

```
$ sort -t '<' -u -k1,1 file
111<vvv>222<vvv>333
aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
```

This is essentially the second step in the above pipeline and it sorts the file on the first field while removing duplicates.

---

An `awk` solution would look like

```
$ awk -F '<' '!seen[$1]++' file
aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
111<vvv>222<vvv>333
```

This stores the first field as a key in an associative array called `seen` and post-increments the associated value.  If the value in the array for the given key is zero (i.e., this first field has not been seen before), the line is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Or equivalently with neither `awk` nor `cut`, but with `sed`:

```
$ sed '=' file \
      | sed 'N;s/\n/</' \
      | sort -t"<" -u -k2,2 \
      | sort -t"<" -k1,1 \
      | sed 's/^[0-9]*<//'
aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
111<vvv>222<vvv>333
```

But this is **very** clunky. @Kusalananda's last (awk-based) solution is **much** better.

---

Just for pedagogy's sake, the two first `sed` blocks above, are equivalent to Kusalananda's more compact `awk` cmd :

- `sed '=' file`, prints line numbers for future ordering
- `sed 'N;s/\n/</'`, appends the next input line in pattern space (i.e. "joins current and next lines") and substitutes the end-of-line `\n` with `<`.

The 3rd and last `sed` tidbit, `sed 's/^[0-9]*<//'`, substitutes the line number and "<" placed earlier at the beginning of each line, with nothing.

---

For more details on `sed`, issue `$ info sed` in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed we can do the task as given :

```
$ sed -Ene '
   G
   /^([^<]+)<vvv>.*\n\1(\n|$)/d
   P;s/<vvv>.*//;H
 ' input.txt
```

Store the first field in hold space and compare it to the current line's first field.
Only when they differ, update the hold as also print the current line.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below 2 methods

```
Method1

 awk -F "<" '{if (!seen[$1]++)print }' filename

Method2

awk -F "<" '!a[$1]++' filename
```

output

```
aaa<vvv>bbb<vvv>ccc
xxx<vvv>yyy<vvv>zzz
111<vvv>222<vvv>333
```